# Node-Schedule Triggering Issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am creating a function on my server which is supposed to trigger daily, but not only does it not trigger as expected it triggers every time the server is reset (which it did not do yesterday). The data only needs updated once a day and rapidapi is pay per api call after 100 calls a day, so I'm really trying to get this scheduled job working.

I've only tried node-schedule on my server, which has a dependency of CRON (which is why scheduleJob is using the CRON format). Originally the function triggered as fast as my computer could refresh the server, so I know the scheduleJob is stopping the API call from being constant.

```
schedule.scheduleJob('* * */23 * *', function () {
  console.log('Daily API call initiated.');
  unirest.get("https://unogs-unogs-v1.p.rapidapi.com/aaapi.cgi?q=get:exp:US&t=ns&st=adv&p=1")
    .header("X-RapidAPI-Host", "unogs-unogs-v1.p.rapidapi.com")
    .header("X-RapidAPI-Key", `${keys.RICHARD_UNOGS_KEY}`)
    .end(function (result) {
      console.log(result.status, result.headers);
      //console.log(result.body) to see all data
      let data = JSON.stringify(result.body)
      fs.writeFile('./movieData.json', data)
    });
})
```

Is there a better way to write this function or achieve the desired results? I only need it triggering once per day, but my computer isn't on 24/7. Since I'm still developing the app, I don't think hosting the server on Heroku or another platform is time-efficient, but I'm more than willing to try it if it'll solve my issue.

The main goal is to tell my server to run it once a day, but to check if it was run in the last 24 hours. If it hasn't been run, run it.

ANSWERED BY jakemingolla: My CRON expression was incorrectly formatted for my intended use. * * */23 * * has the function triggering on every 23rd day (today is the 24th, +1 for index value) with no limitation or other value. That's why my function was calling constantly today. I changed my CRON expression to `15 9 * * *` to trigger my API call every morning at 0915 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure your CRON format is correct based on https://crontab.guru. Based on `* * */23 * *`, that would correspond to "“At every minute on every 23rd day-of-month", which does not sound like what you want.

For example, the CRON string `0 0 * * * *` is every day at midnight. I would update that CRON string to see if it helps alleviate the problem.

Comment: so if i did ```* */23 * * *``` it would be every 23rd hour (midnight)? Also, if I wrote it to trigger on the 23rd day and today is the 24th (+1 index value) that explains why it is triggering constantly today. EDIT: I only mentioned the */23 for midnight just to try and get a better understanding of the CRON format. I know the 0 0 will work.

Comment: I dont think that is the correct CRON expression - I would experiment more with the website I linked above to hopefully get one that matches your use case.